# JTable vs. custom TableModel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to implement a JTable on a Java GUI that can fill itself with values from a file and allow the user to make modifications to various cells.  Since I'm using the GUI editor in the Netbeans IDE, my first instinct was to add the JTable to my form from the palette.  however, I quickly realized that I couldn't add more than 100 rows to the table (for my application i'd need around 500+).  additionally, while searching for a solution to this problem, I noticed a lot of people saying to use a Custom TableModel instead of using the JTable because it is more robust/efficient.

first, is there a way to add more than 100 rows to a JTable?  secondly, is using the JTable (which uses the DefaultTableModel) really a bad implementation?  my form is pretty complex, so I would prefer to use the GUI editor to adjust the size, position, etc. of my JTable as opposed to hard-coding it.

Comment: DefaultTableModel isn't the most efficient, especially for large datasets, but it should probably be adequate for 500 rows.  As for your issue with 100 rows, not sure I understand.  If the JTable is inside a JScrollPane that should be no problem.

Comment: really?, it seemed like the jtable already included a scroll pane by default - except that it only scrolls to 100 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to add more than 100 rows to a JTable?

Why is 100 a limit? That sounds like your IDE, not the DefaultTableModel. Tens of thousands of rows is no problem for the DefaultTableModel (not that any user would want to look at all that data).

Comment: it's a limit of jtable, not the defaulttablemodel itself.

Comment: No it is not a limit of the JTable. A JTable will display whatever is contained in the TableModel.

Comment: well then it must be netbeans, though i don't understand why they would use such an arbitrary limit.  the problem arises whenever i try to add more rows by hardcoding as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most Swing GUI coders that I know don't "hard-code" their GUI's but rather use the easier to use layout managers (BorderLayout, GridLayout, BoxLayout, FlowLayout, MigLayout, FormLayout, etc...) to do the heavy lifting for them and to allow their complex GUI's to be resizeable and decent looking on multiple platforms. Regarding your other issue, it's not whether to use a JTable or a custom model since if you're using a JTable, you'll be using a JTable whether or not the model is default or custom, but if you're doing anything complex, then yeah, you'll likely want to add your own TableModel to your JTable. They're not that hard to create, and w can help you with it.  I do wonder about your 500 line requirement -- there's no way that anyone will need or want to look at 500 lines at one time. Perhaps you want to use a database and load and remove rows into your TableModel as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple to increase rows manually rather than to increase them through GUI :

1. Right Click on your newly designed jTable
2. Select Customize Code
3. Change the DEFAULT CODE to CUSTOMER PROPERTY (where the object creation started for rows)
4. By Default null rows are 100
5. COPY and PASTE the the NULL rows as maximum you need
6. CLICK ok.  Now your table rows size INCREASED as needed